# Unit testing in Node Js not working for res.end()

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I am testing node files with Mocha and sinon. Below is a little piece of code that I would like to test and get coverage report.

```
if (sfError) {
            //do something

            res.status(401);
            res.end();
            return;
}
```

I am not able to cover res.end and return. How do I do that? Any help would be a great favor.

Answer (score 0):

If using express 4.x: `res.status(401).send();`

Comment: I do not have to modify the file which I am going to test. Any other idea using any stubs, mock or something.?

Answer (score -1):

replace

```
res.status(401);
res.end();
```

with

```
res.status(401).end();
```

Comment: I do not have to modify the file which I am going to test. Any other idea using any stubs, mock or something.?